# Delete rows with multiple conditons using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a raw data in excel as xls extention. 
I want to delete the rows based on 3 conditions.

1. delete the row which has field with text "No" in column c
2. delete the row which has field with text " ExtBUD" and "ExtItaly" in column D
3. delete the blank rows in both columns C and D.

here is the data

```
      A            B               C               D
       Fname         Lname        activeconnect      Clustername
1.     ram           raju            Yes             ExtIndia
2.     John          reynold         Yes             ExtBUD
3.     Sree           olaf           No              ExtUSA
4.                consider as Blank row
5.     alois         lobmier           No             ExtPeru
6.      Niko          papa            yes             ExtItaly
```

The sample output should be as follows

```
         A            B               C               D
       Fname         Lname        activeconnect      Clustername
1.     ram           raju            Yes             ExtIndia
```

Here my code  works for the first condition and also delete the row which has field with "ExtBUD". can anyone help me please

```
Sub Import()
lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

row_number = 1
Do
DoEvents
   row_number = row_number + 1
   active_connect = Sheets("WX Messenger Export 20150819").Range("U" & row_number)
   cluster_name = Sheets("WX Messenger Export 20150819").Range("X" & row_number)
   If InStr(active_connect, "No") >= 1 Then
   If InStr(cluster_name, "ExtBUD") >= 1 And InStr(cluster_name, "ExtItaly") >= 1 Then

   Sheets("WX Messenger Export 20150819").Rows(row_number & ":" & row_number).Delete
   row_number = row_number - 1
   End If
    End If

 Loop Until active_connect = ""

End Sub
```

Comment: if this is a one-off exercise, you may want to use Autofilters to filter relevant rows and delete them

Answer (score 0):

In case of `If Then` you have to use `or` in the condition

```
Sub Import()
lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

row_number = 1
Do
DoEvents
   row_number = row_number + 1
   active_connect = Sheets("WX Messenger Export 20150819").Range("U" & row_number)
   cluster_name = Sheets("WX Messenger Export 20150819").Range("X" & row_number)
   If InStr(active_connect, "No") >= 1 or (InStr(cluster_name, "ExtBUD") >= 1 And InStr(cluster_name, "ExtItaly") >= 1) Then 

   Sheets("WX Messenger Export 20150819").Rows(row_number & ":" & row_number).Delete
   row_number = row_number - 1
   End If

 Loop Until active_connect = ""

End Sub
```

but you still haven't check the blank rows. therefore add the following part to the if condition too: `or (Sheets("WX Messenger Export 20150819").Range("C" & row_number) = "" and Sheets("WX Messenger Export 20150819").Range("D" & row_number) = "")`

The final code would be

```
Sub Import()
lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

row_number = 1
Do
DoEvents
   row_number = row_number + 1
   active_connect = Sheets("WX Messenger Export 20150819").Range("U" & row_number)
   cluster_name = Sheets("WX Messenger Export 20150819").Range("X" & row_number)
   If InStr(active_connect, "No") >= 1 or (InStr(cluster_name, "ExtBUD") >= 1 And InStr(cluster_name, "ExtItaly") >= 1) or (Sheets("WX Messenger Export 20150819").Range("C" & row_number) = "" and Sheets("WX Messenger Export 20150819").Range("D" & row_number) = "") Then 

   Sheets("WX Messenger Export 20150819").Rows(row_number & ":" & row_number).Delete
   row_number = row_number - 1
   End If

 Loop Until active_connect = ""

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
Public Sub deleteRow()

    Dim row, lastRow As Integer

    With Sheets("WX Messenger Export 20150819")

        'Set the start row
        row = 2

        'Get the last row
        lastRow = .Range("A2").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).row

        'loop from first row to last row
        Do While row <= lastRow

            'If condition are equal, delete row
            If .Range("C" & row) = "No" Or .Range("D" & row) = "ExtBUD" Or .Range("D" & row) = "ExtItaly" Or (.Range("C" & row) = "" And .Range("D" & row) = "") Then

                .Rows(row).Delete

                lastRow = lastRow - 1

            'Else go to next row
            Else

                row = row + 1

            End If

        Loop

    End With

End Sub
```